# Make HTTP 1.0 Request in Go

Tags: go, go-http

is there any way to make a HTTP 1.0 Request ?

Go always reverts to using HTTP 1.1

I have tried setting the request.Proto to HTTP 1.0 but it didnt change anything

Comment: What is your goal of using 1.0?  Do you want to avoid chunked encoding, disable keep alive or something else?

Comment: @CeriseLimón i have a server im trying to contact that only responds to HTTP 1.0 requests, all other requests it responds as 403 forbidden

Comment: Most HTTP/1.1 features can be disabled, but it's not possible to force the request proto to HTTP/1.1.  One alternative is to write an HTTP/1.0 client. It's not a large amount of code given how simple the protocol is.  There may be third party libraries that support HTTP/1.0. Note questions seeking recommendations on libraries are off topic on SO.